# Python on mac: error during reading from numbers file

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I want to read from my numbers-sheet some data. The first row is a "title" row, containing names of each column, and every other row contains data.
I wrote a simple program in python to read this, however every time when I run this code I get:

```
File "dataReader.py", line 11, in <module>
    for row in fileReader:
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte
```

I was trying to encode each line, but it doesn't helped.
Below I past my code (in this one I am not calling the utf_8_encoder function, but even if I try to use it - I still have errors).
I want to read row by row from my file, and read it as a string. 
How can I do that?

```
import csv
import codecs

def utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data):
    for line in unicode_csv_data:
        yield line.encode('utf-8')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dataFile = open("file.numbers", 'rU')
    fileReader = csv.reader(dataFile)
    for row in fileReader:
        print row
```

Here is also a sample of my file:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps try using `fileReader = csv.reader(x.replace('\0', '') for x in dataFile)`

Comment: May be open file in binary mode (rb instead of rU)?

Comment: How did you create the data file? More specifically, did you save it as a CSV file?

Comment: @Robᵩ Us you can see, the file is saved as .numbers, not .csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have saved the file as a `.numbers` file, not as a CSV file. The csv module is used to read CSV (comma-separated value) files, and cannot interpret a `.numbers` file.

To make your program work, save your data as a CSV file.